# ActiveX Textbox not updating until Design View is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex

I have a lot of text boxes updating to match cell references via a macro. The macro is simple, it sets value of textbox to "", then sets it = to a cell reference (example below).

```
ActiveSheet.HTMLText99.Value = ""
ActiveSheet.HTMLText99.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
```

The odd thing is when I run the macro, the values dont change until I click the "Design View" in the developer tab. Is there a better way to be clearing the values or is there an updating script i should be using?

Comment: Is `Application.ScreenUpdating` off?

Comment: No, screen updating is on